Access - delete data only from form, not from table
Hy,
I`m trying to delete data records only from an access form - not from the table. I have different forms - all created via a query from a table. I have a function, which prints the data inside this forms as tags. Now I would like to delete some entries from these forms, so that not always all data from the form are printed. But I don´t want to delete these entries on the table itself, just in the different forms. Is there any way to do this?

That's easy. Don't "print" the values to those tags or, if they have been "printed", clear those prints. However, I looks like you need to read up on how to use Access, so browse for a tutorial/guide "Starting with Microsoft Access" or simimlar.

Add a field to the table like "DoNotShow" as boolean. Change the the record source of your form so that records with DoNotShow=true will be excluded. In the form itself you can add a button to set DoNotShow=true for the current record and then you can set a form.requery to load the records new, now without the just marked record.

@Zen : thanks, this is working for my problem. THANK YOU!!!

Are you the only user of this db? If there are multiple simultaneous users setting this check field, they will conflict.

@June7 : Yes, I´m the only one
